# How do I modify the Javadoc when I modify someone else's code?

Tags: java, javadoc

I am working on someone else's code and making significant modifications.  (I am converting it to use a different database than the one he originally used.)  How do I indicate in the Javadoc comments that I am not the original author of the code, but that I did make contributions to it.  Is there a clean or standard way of doing this already?  My Googling is not helping me figure this out.

Example:

```
/**
* This class does some really awesome stuff.
* 
* @author Steph the Great - Modified to use PostgreSQL instead of Derby;
*         added comments to the code
*/
```

I also don't know the original author's name, so all I can put down is myself . . .

Comment: I would not get too stressed. If you feel it's important to differentiate your work from the original authors you can use inline comments to highlight your changes or just add a comment to the javadoc saying some like "Modified <date> to do ... by ..." or whatever suites you. People generally only get upset about changes to code if someone wreaks it and doesn't comment, thus labeling the original author as a bad programmer. As long as you add something to say you've changed it and are not the original author you should be fine. And in a lot of cases, it won't matter if you don't :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Those comments *do not belong in the javadoc* :-) The javadoc should explain the contract -- it is what is extracted and displayed in the auto-generated "documentation". The rest are just normal comments or, perhaps better yet in this case, SCM log entries and have no place in the javadoc!

I would likely just leave the original author, but if you want credit...

...see the [@author](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@author) javadoc reference and note that it can be included multiple times. This section [explicitly relates to multiple authors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#multiple@author) and ordering, etc.

```
/**
* This class does some really awesome stuff.
* It uses PostreSQL. 
*
* @author Steph the Great
* @author Freddy Four Fingers
*/
// DEC2012 - Fred - Modified to use PostgreSQL instead of Derby (but really, use SCM!)
class Awesome { ... }
```

Happy coding.

---

Notes on question somewhat unrelated to example in post... if the author isn't known, then several things can be done. First and foremost *add a link or reference to where the original source was obtained* -- an optional "I didn't write this originally" for clarity can be noted as well.

Then, depending upon your preference:

1. *Don't specify* an `@author` field -- not even yourself. *It's not required.*
2. Add yourself as the sole author; the original source is mentioned above in the javadoc
3. Add a dummy author and yourself as the second author, e.g. <del>`@author Unknown`</del> `@author unascribed` (see comments and [@author](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@author)).
4. Do whatever you want within terms of the license, if any.

Comment: Well, the other problem is I don't know the original author because he didn't write a single comment in his code.  I would feel weird just putting my name as the author alone, though, since it would look like I was taking all his credit.  Do you think I should just omit my own name and have no authors listed?  I can't decide what the best approach would be here.

Comment: +1 for "Those comments do not belong in the javadoc."  I ruthlessly delete `@author` tags in our codebase: they don't add any value beyond what we already have in our source control system, and they actually have *negative* value as soon as they get out of date.

Comment: @Daniel: `@author` tags are good for determining whom to blame if there are "questions" about the code. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: No, that's what `svn blame` (or the equivalent in your preferred SCM) is for.

Comment: @pst: (Re edit.) When authorship is unknown, the standard placeholder name is "unascribed". See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html for more details.

Comment: @Steph: If you don't know the original author, how do you know that you are allowed to edit the code at all? Not indicating authorship is not equivalent to public domain, you should know.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: The code belongs to the company I work for and was written by someone who used to work here.  I'm not stealing anything.

Answer (score 12):

You can have more than one `@author` tag. So, if you've made extensive changes to a class, just add a new `@author` tag with your own name in it. There's no need to list the changes you've done---the revision history should show that well enough.

Comment: Okay.  I just feel weird putting my name down as the author, since I don't know the guy's name who wrote this originally and can't put him down as well.  It feels like I'm taking credit for his code.

Comment: @Steph: In that case, put `@author unascribed` first, then add your own `@author` tag. "Unascribed" is the standard name used when the authorship is unknown. (Many classes in the JDK, dating back to the 1.0 or earlier days, have `@author unascribed`. Just for fun, Google for "author unascribed". :-))